# Regex for parsing string with same type of expression

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex parsing in java. I want to parse the string which contain the records. But I want to select the selected part of that record only.

```
\"6\":\"Services Ops\",\"practice_name\":\"Services Ops\",\"7\":\"Management\",
```

For this, I have written regex expression as

```
(^\\\"6\\\":\\\"[A-Za-z \s]*)
```

and above expression gives me result as : `\"6\":\"Services Ops\`

I want only `Service Ops`

And also there are multiple records like \"5"\:\"xxx"\ and so on thus if I write the expression for only `Service Ops` then entries from other fields are also included in the result of the expression.

Is there any way that we can select the string which start with some `pattern` but we can exclude that pattern.

Like in above example, string starting with `\"6\":\"` but we can exclude this part and get only `Service Ops` as result.

Thank you.

Comment: That input looks suspiciously like json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookarounds which perform only a check but don't match:

```
lookahead (?=...)
lookbehind(?<=...)
```

example:

```
(?<=\\\"6\\\":\\\")[^\"]++(?=\")
```

An another way is to use a capturing group `(...)`:

```
\\\"6\\\":\\\"([^\"]++)\"
```

Then you can extract only the content of the group. Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\"6\\\":\\\"([^\"]++)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```